# Typo3: Add class to default content wrap

Tags: html, css, typo3, typoscript

I want to add a class to the default content wrap

```
<div id="c8" class="csc-default myclass"></div>
```

but I don't know how to override.

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.??.??.??
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah finally I found it using the typoscript object browser:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {

  default.20.10.value = csc-default myClass

}
```

Thanks anyway